Gatsby: Google Tag Manager (GTM) Not Firing on Page Navigation
I'm experiencing an issue with Google Tag Manager (GTM) integration on my Gatsby site. Here's the situation:
Issue: GTM tags fire correctly on the initial page load, but when navigating between pages using Gatsby's built-in navigation (without a full-page reload), the tags are not firing as expected. This issue is reflected in the GTM dashboard, where no tag events are recorded after page transitions.
Setup: I'm using gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager to configure GTM. I have also enabled enableWebVitalsTracking. While tags seem to work on the initial page load, they aren't being triggered for subsequent page views.
I suspect this has something to do with how Gatsby handles navigation with its built-in Link component (which prevents full reloads). Does anyone know how to make GTM properly track page views in this setup, or have suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
So far, we've configured the gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager in our gatsby-config.js file as shown below (with the actual GTM ID masked). We’ve enabled tag firing in development builds and enabled web vitals tracking, but the tags still aren't firing on page transitions:
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
  options: {
    id: "GTM-XXXXX", // Replace with your actual GTM ID
    includeInDevelopment: true, // Enabled for development builds
    enableWebVitalsTracking: true, // Web vitals tracking
    defaultDataLayer: function () {
      return {
        pageType: window.pageType,
      };
    },
  },
},

